# Jest mocked api call failing to return data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, jestjs

I have the following cusotm React hook:

```
...
    useEffect(() => {
        const handleMonitoringData = async (isDefaultProduct?: boolean) => {
            const result = await getMonitoringData(intermediaryId);
            if (result) {
                const sortedResult = result.sort((a, b) =>
                    a.product?.name > b.product?.name ? 0 : -1
                );

                setMonitoringData(sortedResult);
                if (isDefaultProduct) selectProduct(sortedResult[0]);
            }
        };

        if (isSuperUser) {
            setMonitoringData([]);
            selectProduct(null);

            if (hasRendered) {
                handleMonitoringData();
            } else {
                toggleHasRendered(true);
            }
        } else {
            handleMonitoringData(true);
        }
    }, [intermediaryId]);
...
```

and my attempt at testing the initial monitoring data load (precisely the else statement => `handleMonitoringData(true)`) like so:

```
jest.mock('@api/Monitoring', () => ({
    getMonitoringData: () => [mockedData],
}));

describe('useFundRaising custom hook', () => {
    it('should work', async () => {
        function TestComponent() {
            const { monitoringData } = useFundRaising();

            return <div>{console.log('data: ', monitoringData)}</div>;
        }

        const res = await render(<TestComponent />);
    });
});
```

`getMonitoringData`:

```
export const getMonitoringData = async (
    intermediaryId?: string
): Promise<MonitoringData[]> => {
    const URL = intermediaryId
        ? `${MONITORING_DATA_URL}/${intermediaryId}`
        : MONITORING_DATA_URL;

    const result = await Http.get<MonitoringData[]>(URL);
    return result;
};
```

the test is currently failing: [image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to mock like this:

```js
const mockGetMonitoringData = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockedData);

jest.mock('@api/Monitoring', () => ({
  getMonitoringData: () => mockGetMonitoringData(),
}));
```

as the `getMonitoringData` is an `async` method.